# ssd msata hot temperature hp on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, ssd, temperature

my laptop hard disk temperature is really hot
with win8 is stable and not became hot.

i search but not found nothing working for me

i have no idea of what i must do

ubuntu first is installed on the not ssd hard disk,
i copy all the os and change /etc/fstab

`UUID=67dee7a2-85f3-489e-8d19-9e05d3ccc05e /               ext4    discard,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0       1`





smartctl say

`194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   011   011   000    Old_age   Always       -       89 (Min/Max 29/89)`

`sudo hddtemp /dev/sd[a-b]
/dev/sda: WDC WD10JPVT-60A1YT0: 51°C
/dev/sdb: Crucial_CT250MX200SSD3: 88°C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way that i found is enable all the option for saving power on `powertop`

i add this line to `/etc/rc.local`

`sudo powertop --auto-tune`

for now my ssd is around 61°

i hope in a better solution or this post is usefull for other